# Can't find the option to export billing?

Tags: google-cloud-platform

I do not have the option to export my billing data on the billing page for my project?

I have tried looking in the google docs, but can not see the option to export billing - the only tabs I have are the Overview, Reports and Account Management tabs on the left side bar.

Is there a setting somewhere I need to enable exports?

Comment: Hi, i think you are asking about this https://cloud.google.com/billing/docs/how-to/export-data-file

Comment: Hi, yes I have followed those steps but at step 5 (From the Billing menu on the left, click Billing export) I have no option of selecting billing export? I just have the Overview, Reports and Account Management options.

Comment: what is your IAM role in this project? You will need Billing Account Administrator to export billing.

Comment: I am an Owner. I don't have the option to add Billing Account Administrator to my IAM, however I can see it in the list of roles. No other members in the project seem to have that role either. Thanks

Comment: Is your billing account part of an organization? Project Owner does not have all permissions. Some permissions such as Billing need to be added manually. If you cannot add the permission look into why. Edit your question with more details.

Answer (score 0):

the same issue happened to me, what I did is, I deleted the project and create a new one. In the new project, everything looks good and makes sense.
I am understanding this is not the root cause, guessing it is a bug in CGP :)